# Convert the curl example to Requests util usage

Tags: php, http, curl

I use the [Requests](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) for http request:

I also package it to a util function:

```
function http_util($url, $params, $add_headers = null, $base_url = null ){

    $headers = array('Accept'=>'application/json');

    if($add_headers){
        $headers = array_merge($headers, $add_headers);
    }

    if($base_url) {
        $url = $base_url . $url;
    }

    $request = Requests::post($url, $headers, $params);

    return $request;
}
```

but I found, such as the curl example:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

if the curl example convert to use my http_util, how to use? I am not sure whether my http_util will have more optimize action. and how to use the http_util request the curl example?

Comment: try this tool: [Convert cURL command syntax to Python requests, Node.js code](https://curl.trillworks.com/#php)

Comment: @Lycho Thanks brother, this is so useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use it as-is you'll need to add the `$options` param as noted in the docs: http://requests.ryanmccue.info/docs/authentication.html

The "util" function is simply setting a content `Accept` header. Not worth writing a function for that.

```
$result = Requests::post('http://localhost:8000/o/token' [
    // headers
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
 ], [
    // data
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'username' => '<user_name>',
    'password' => '<password>',
], [
    // options
    'auth' => new Requests_Auth_Basic(['<client_id>', '<client_secret>'])
]);
```